# References for Fermi surface nesting in the context of Kondo physics

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations

I am looking for references that discuss the onset of Fermi surface nesting in the presence of some Kondo interaction. Specifically, I am looking for a discussion of how the coupling of itinerant conduction electrons to localized spins results in the nesting instability. I am looking for references that are more detailed, pedagogical reviews at the advanced research level than contemporary active research, but anything will be greatly appreciated.